# How to display a listview and a webview in one Activity?

Tags: android, api, listview, search, webview

So I'm trying to implement two API in one Activity, and display both the listview and a webview for my second API in the same Activity. I managed to get the listview down. This is part of the MainActivity where I'm trying to call both run both API's through the onClick method

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.twit_list);
    activity = this;

    Key = getStringFromManifest("CONSUMER_KEY");
    Secret = getStringFromManifest("CONSUMER_SECRET");

    txtSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSearch);
    searchbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchbtn);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    savedSearches = (Button)findViewById(R.id.savedSearches);

    searchbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
    public void onClick(View view){

            downloadSearches();
            new GoogleSearch();


        }
    });
    save.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveSearch();

        }
    });

    savedSearches.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
            openSavedSearches();
        }
    });

}
```

This is the GoogleSearch Api 
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.twit_list);

```
    txtSearch = (EditText)webView.findViewById(R.id.txtSearch);
    searchbtn = (Button) webView.findViewById(R.id.searchbtn);
    webView = (WebView)webView.findViewById(R.id.webView);

    searchbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String item = txtSearch.getText().toString();
            new JsonSearchTask(item).execute();
        }
    });
}

    private class JsonSearchTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        String searchResult = "";
        String search_url =   "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=";
        String search_query;

        JsonSearchTask(String item){

            try {
                search_item = URLEncoder.encode(item, "utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            search_query = search_url + search_item;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            try {
                searchResult = ParseResult(sendQuery(search_query));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            searchbtn.setEnabled(false);
            searchbtn.setText("Wait...");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            webView.loadData(searchResult,
                    "text/html",
                    "UTF-8");

            searchbtn.setEnabled(true);
            searchbtn.setText("Search");

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }

private String sendQuery(String query) throws IOException{
    String result = "";

    URL searchURL = new URL(query);

    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) searchURL.openConnection();

    if(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                inputStreamReader,
                8192);

        String line = null;
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            result += line;
        }

        bufferedReader.close();
    }

    return result;
}

private String ParseResult(String json) throws JSONException{
    String parsedResult = "";

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONObject jsonObject_responseData = jsonObject.getJSONObject("responseData");
    JSONArray jsonArray_results = jsonObject_responseData.getJSONArray("results");

    //parsedResult += "Google Search APIs (JSON) for : <b>" + search_item + "</b><br/>";
    //parsedResult += "Number of results returned = <b>" + jsonArray_results.length() + "</b><br/><br/>";

    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray_results.length(); i++){

        JSONObject jsonObject_i = jsonArray_results.getJSONObject(i);

        String iTitle = jsonObject_i.getString("title");
        String iContent = jsonObject_i.getString("content");
        String iUrl = jsonObject_i.getString("url");

        parsedResult += "<a href='" + iUrl + "'>" + iTitle + "</a><br/>";
        parsedResult += iContent + "<br/><br/>";
    }

    return parsedResult;
}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id = "@+id/activitymain"
>




<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id = "@+id/txtSearch"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtSearch"
        android:text="Search"
        android:id="@+id/searchbtn" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtSearch"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/searchbtn"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/searchbtn"
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:text="     Save     " />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Saved Searches"
        android:id="@+id/savedSearches"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/save"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/save"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/save" />
</RelativeLayout>



<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="174dp"
    android:id = "@android:id/list"
    android:background="#FF498CDE">

</ListView>

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="202dp"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Basically I want to run both api's when I click the search button.
Please someone point me in the right direction, I'm completely new to this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem is that you are not getting any response in your JsonSearchTask AsyncTask.**

The problem is that the api you are using for the google web search is not available now. You should use Google Custom Search API (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/).